# Is it possible to approximate the volume of a Torus using Riemann sums?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

To preface, I am a poor undergrad who's only in Calculus 1. Instead of studying for my final exam, I decided to test my knowledge by writing a program that calculates Riemann Sum approximations of areas under curves between two points on a graph.

Naturally, I thought this was pretty cool and sent it to a friend who's a Stats PhD with a math B.S. His response was to try and adjust the program to find the volume of a Torus with r=1. I have no idea how to approach this, but I am not one to back away from a challenge.

So far, my knowledge of Riemann sums is obviously on a 2D plane with the form

$$A = \Delta x[f(x_0) + f(x_1) +...f(x_n)]$$

Comment: I might start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution -- then use either washers (discussed at disc method) or shells (discussed at cylinder method).  Have you studied volumes of revolution?

Comment: @EricTowers No, my professor skipped it because he deemed it useless

Comment: I have several friends and acquaintances whose need to estimate material consumption for 3d-printed volumes of revolution puts the lie to your professor's deeming.  However, this suggests you have access to a text that describes the method and shows examples.

Comment: @EricTowers Fair enough. I will look into the link you sent, thank you!